# argument 2 has type int * and want to read a file

Tags: c, linux, int, fopen, scanf

There seems to be some error when reading the line

> States 10

How would I save the number 10 to an integer names states? Eventually I will read three more lines of that are `%c %i` so I can save three more variables. The `fscanf` is easier to use than `strtok`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>



//any?
///
/// main function
/// @author jw
/// @param 
/// @param 
/// @returns 
///
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    FILE *fp;


    fp = fopen( argv[1], "r" );
    if( fp == NULL ) {
            //something went wrong
            perror( argv[1] );
            exit( 1 );
        }

        int states = 0;

        //print the first 3 lines using sscanf()
        // then capitalize on that matrix
        //
        fscanf(fp, "%i",&states  );
        printf("Number found is %i", &states);
    }
```

Compiler Output:

```
 tokenize.c: In function 'main':
    tokenize.c:33:3: warning: format '%i' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 2 has type 'int *' [-Wformat=]
       printf("Number found is %i", &states);
       ^
    tokenize.c:14:14: warning: unused parameter 'argc' [-Wunused-parameter]
     int main(int argc, char* argv[])
                  ^
    gcc -ggdb -Wall -std=c99 -pedantic -Wextra -o tokenize tokenize.o
```

Comment: Now the code only prints "The number of states is 0"

Comment: The line I read should be States 10, and I don't know how to select the int 10 so I changed code to fscanf(fp, "%c%i, letter, &states); and added char letter;

Comment: What do these comments mean? Can you please stay on topic.

Comment: Yes I will update the question in 2 minutes.

Comment: No, please don't do that. You've asked the question. Please let's stay on topic and deal with the question that you asked.

Comment: Well I just did and rewrote the next step which was the output. I can make another question but its the same code and someone who knows fscanf will see this as a relative topic, right?

Comment: I reverted your edit. You cannot ask a question, get answers, and then edit away the original question making those answers completely invalid. Please ask a new question if you have a different question.

Comment: Thank you @DavidHeffernan, but I can't since I am receiving negative feedback for this discussion. $%#$%!!!

Comment: Maybe you can get some hints from this article about how to write better questions: http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, change this

```
printf("Number found is %i", &states);
```

to

```
printf("Number found is %i", states);
```

`printf()` takes the integer variable and not the pointer to the integer variable.

Answer (score 2):

The line in question is

```
printf("Number found is %i", &states);
```

and the compiler says:

```
warning: format '%i' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 2 has type 'int *'
```

Just as the compiler says, it expects you to pass `int`, but you pass `int*`. You need to write:

```
printf("Number found is %i", states);
```

With `fscanf` you passed `&states`, the address of the variable, because you needed `fscanf` to modify the variable. But for the call to `printf`, no modification is made to the variable and you must pass `states`, the value of the variable.